# Помогите перевести в с++

Tags: c++

```
var
  f : boolean;

  alpha, beta, gamma, a, b, c : real;

  {alpha - угол напротив стороны a, beta - напротив b, gamma - напротив c}
 
function arccos(x : real) : real;

begin
     arccos := 2 * arctan(sqrt((1 - x) / (1 + x)))
end;
 
begin

  repeat

    f := true;

    write('введите A B C: ');

    readln(a, b, c);

    if (a + b <= c) or (a + c <= b) or (b + c <= a) then

    begin

      writeln('треугольник с такими сторонами не существует');

      f := false

    end

  until f = true;

  {по теореме косинусов}

  alpha := arccos((sqr(b) + sqr(c) - sqr(a))/(2 * b * c)) * 180 / pi;

  beta := arccos((sqr(a) + sqr(c) - sqr(b))/(2 * a * c)) * 180 / pi;

  gamma := 180 - alpha - beta;

  writeln('значения углов: ', alpha:5:2, ' ' , beta:5:2, ' ', gamma:5:2)

end.
```

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не получается? Только не говорите, что опыт программирования на С++ у вас всего 5 минут))

Comment: вы совершенно правы

Answer (score 3):

опыт программирования всего 1 час поможет решить эту проблему :)

вам потребуется

1. присваивания `=`,
2. считывания от пользователя `std::cin`,
3. вывод на экран `std::cout`
4. корень `sqrt`
5. арккосинус `acos`
6. цикл `do while`
7. скобки `{}` вместо `begin/end` и
8. библиотеки `#include <cmath>` и `#include <iostream>`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хорошо попробую

Comment: *`"библиотеки #include <cmath> и #include <iostream>"`* -- с каких пор заголовочные файлы стали *библиотеками*?